# how to pack 4 9-bit and 1 4-bit int variable into 5 8-bit variable in python?

Tags: python, bit, pack

I have 4 variable between `0~0x1FF(9-bit)` and 1 variable between `0~0xF(4-bit)` and I want to pack them into binary. As usual, I will pack the first four with `pack('H', var)`(**unsigned short, 16-bit**), then pack the last one with `pack('B', var)`(**unsigned char, 8-bit**).

so I will cost `72 bits`:

```
16 * 4 + 8 = 72
```

I am facing a special situation: my storage is very very precious, I just need 40 bits:

```
4 * 9 + 1 * 4
```

I waste 32 bits, and also these 32 bits can be important to me, because I have a lot of data to pack, every time I waste 32 bits, at last, my storage complains to me.

In fact, I can change 4 9-bit variable and 1 4-bit variable into 5 8-bit variable(unsigned char), then I pack them all with `pack('B', var)`, of course I save 32 bits.

```
4 * 9 + 1 * 4 == 5 * 8
```

**How can I simply change pack 4 9-bit variable and 1 4-bit variable int 5 8-bit variable?**

Comment: 1) Don't spam tags! This is not related to C. 2) Use bitops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pack them yourself:

```
import struct
ninebits = [0b110011001,0b000000000,0b111111111,0b010101010]
fourbit = 0b1010
pack = 0
for i,v in enumerate(ninebits):
    pack <<= 9
    pack |= v
pack <<= 4
pack |= fourbit
print('{:040b}'.format(pack))
print('{:010X}'.format(pack))
print(struct.pack('>LB',pack >> 8, pack & 0xFF))
```

Output:

```
1100110010000000001111111110101010101010
CC803FEAAA
b'\xcc\x80?\xea\xaa'
```

Note that `?` is ASCII for `\x3f`.

Comment: I don't think that it is doable directly with `pack` without going through the shift and adding process you put in the `for` loop?...I'm just trying to figure out a way for that...:P...but nevertheless, great answer +1